# Systems of first order equations with constant coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

Find the fundamental matrix for the system
$$\dot x_1 = x_1 + x_2$$
$$\dot x_2 = x_2 + x_3$$
$$\dot x_3 = x_3$$

I attempted this question using the steps outlined below,

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are determined as,
$$det(A-I\lambda) = \begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 1-\lambda & 1\\\ 0 & 0 & 1-\lambda\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

From the above, I get repeated eigenvalues of 1 (i.e. $\lambda$ = 1).

I am stuck with how to determine the solutions and eigenvectors to this problem since the eigenvalues are repeated. Any help on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: So your question is how to find multiple eigenvectors when the eigenvalue is repeated?

Comment: yes, but precisely how to construct the solution for repeated eigenvalues

Comment: your matrix is **already** in Jordan form. You have $A=I + N$  where $I,N$   commute. And  for real scalar $t$  you have $At = It + Nt$  where $Nt$  and $It$   commute.  So $$  e^{At}  = e^{It}  e^{Nt}  $$  The one with $Nt$ is done by(a finite) power series

Answer (score 1):

This is a triangular system. The last ODE is independent from the others. Once you solve $\dot x_3 = x_3$ as $\hat x_3(t)$ you can substitute in the previous ODE $\dot x_2 = x_2 + \hat x_3$ that will depend only on $\dot x_2$ determining then $\hat x_2(t)$ and finally, the first one as $\dot x_1 = x_1 + \hat x_2$

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{D}=d/dt$

$I: (\hat{D}-1)x_3=0$

$II:(\hat{D}-1)x_2=x_3\implies (\hat{D}-1)^2x_2=0$

$III:(\hat{D}-1)x_1=x_2\implies (\hat{D}-1)^3x_1=0$

$I$ tells us $x_3=C_1e^t$.

I forget the theorem, but there's one that goes if differential operator $\hat{O}$ has repeated eigenvalues, the corresponding eigenvectors are a power of the independent variable times the base case. Info and proof here: [Repeated roots](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/RepeatedRoots.aspx)

Combined with $II$ that tells us $x_2=C_1'e^t+C_2'te^t$

We also apply the principle to $III$ to get $x_1=C_3'e^t+C_4'te^t +C_5't^2e^t$

With this being a system of equations, one can find the relationship between the constants and match against initial values to solve for them.